# how to create a view in hive which always points to the latest partition

Tags: database, hadoop, hive

I have a requirement where I need to create a view in Hive to always point to the latest partition. 
partition column in main table is created like partition_date=000020170606
does anyone know how this can be done?

Comment: How would you define latest partition? Does this partitioned column have values in increasing/descreasing order ?

Comment: @Shubhangi partitioned columns will be dates in increasing order. As a naming convention the the date will be populated after 0000.

Comment: You could configure the Hive Metastore to push a notification message to Oozie (or to a custom service) every time a partition is added. Then you could develop some app logic to check whether the new partition is latest, handle race conditions (i.e. multiple parts created at about the same time), and re-create the view. Good luck.

Comment: Or, you could manage partitition creation and view re-creation via a custom app, using the Metastore Java API. Good luck.